# Populating listview from JSON dynamically when user reaches bottom

Tags: android, android-listview, android-json

I'm populating a `ListView` via JSON. I accomplished it with [this tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html).

The only problem I'm facing: I want to load more items when a user reaches the end of the `ListView`, I don't want to load 100 items at the beginning. I want to show 10 items and then 10 more items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:-
Most of the codes are commented so you can get idea what each statement does.

### Adding a FooterView to the ListView

A footer View is nothing more than a piece of XML that defines how the footer of your listview will look like.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:padding="3dp"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Loading more days..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Its just a simple textview with a message for demonstration purposes. But you can put anything in here :-)

Adding the View to the ListView is not hard. The only thing you need to be aware of is that you put it above the line that adds your adapter to the View! We will use this code to add it to our ListView: [addFooterView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

```
 //add the footer before adding the adapter, else the footer will not load!
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Now the fun part, checking if we are all the way down and loading the items

### Java Implementation

The actual loading is done in a separate thread (Runnable). This way we don't lock the main interface ( GUI ).

```
//Here is where the magic happens
this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
    //useless here, skip!
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
    //dumdumdum
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //what is the bottom iten that is visible
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
        if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){
            Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
});
```

## Implementing Runnables to handle the loading

The loading is done by 2 `Runnables`. The 1st runnable `loadMoreListItems` is called to get the data and the 2nd runnable `returnRes` is called on the main (UI) thread to update the interface. To switch from the 1st to the 2nd we use a method named: [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Here is the code that implements the Runnables, i commented the code as much as i could to make it understandable:

Runnable to load the items

```
   private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
        loadingMore = true;
        //Reset the array that holds the new items
        myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Simulate a delay, delete this on a production environment!
        try { Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        //Get 15 new listitems
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {
            //Fill the item with some bogus information
                myListItems.add("Date: " + (d.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ 1) + "/" + d.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + d.get(Calendar.YEAR) );
            // +1 day
                d.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        //Done! now continue on the UI thread
            runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }
};
```

And the 2nd Runnable:
Since we cant update our UI from a thread this Runnable takes care of that!

```
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Loop thru the new items and add them to the adapter
        if(myListItems != null && myListItems.size() > 0){
                    for(int i=0;i < myListItems.size();i++)
                    adapter.add(myListItems.get(i));
                 }
        //Update the Application title
            setTitle("Neverending List with " + String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()) + " items");
        //Tell to the adapter that changes have been made, this will cause the list to refresh
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Done loading more.
                loadingMore = false;
        }
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CommonsWare EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/) project is intended for this. It says it's retired now with no explanation or replacement listed, but it works perfectly well.